# how can you work with libreoffice via nc without java or python

Tags: libreoffice, uno, libreoffice-writer

I opened the page and tried to run the example
[text](https://pythonhosted.org/iac-protocol/lowriter.html)

nothing succeeded. How does this even work?

`libreoffice "--accept=socket,host=localhost,port=18100;urp;StarOffice.ServiceManager" --norestore --nofirststartwizard --nologo --writer`

this line started writer

Next I ran the bash script. The first question is ports, writer runs on port 18100, and in the bash script 14733

I expected that by calling the script I would receive a file with the transferred string, but nothing happened - does it even work?

I expected that by calling the script I would receive a file with the transferred string, but nothing happened - does it even work?
I need to make a document without resorting to java or python

Comment: What's nc? It sounds like you may be asking about servers rather than programming, so you might get better answers on Server Fault. There's also Unix & Linux and another for Ask Ubuntu. Or if it's about how to use LibreOffice software then there's Super User. The complete list of SE sites is at https://stackexchange.com/sites.

Comment: if you read the wiki, it uses the nc utility to work with sockets.